# How do I see files that is currently in Chrome page's memory?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, blob, fileapi

Is there any way in Google Chrome Dev Tools to see files that have been loaded onto the page from the local machine, and stored as Files or Blobs?

I am using `window.URL.createObjectURL` to preview images that are uploaded to my site. I want to experiment with performance in Chrome and see what is happening behind the scenes.

Here's example code from Mozilla, [live in Codepen](https://codepen.io/raphisama/pen/ExxXYyX).

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    const list = document.createElement("ul");
    fileList.appendChild(list);
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);
      
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      li.appendChild(img);
      const info = document.createElement("span");
      info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
      li.appendChild(info);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<a href="#" id="fileSelect">Select some files</a> 
<div id="fileList">
  <p>No files selected!</p>
</div>
```